# Ordinary Err from fsevents when trying to install VueJs project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, windows-dev-center

Ordinary Err from fsevents when trying to install VueJs project.

I'm using windows 10 as a development platform

I have tried several alternatives without success.

`npm install --no-optional` (Does not work)

`npm install -f` (Does not work)

In this case, it would not be just a warning message. An error is issued and it does not finish compiling the complete code and the server "npm run serves" does not up

Could anyone help?.

```
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","a
rch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to `package.json`:

```
"optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "1.2.12"
  },
```